# First value comma separated string

Tags: php

There will be a string with a single or multiple with no commas at all.

```
$str = "a, b";
```

How do I get the first value before the comma if it contains comma(s)? This is what I did.

```
if(preg_match('/[,]+/', $str, $f)) {
     $firstVal = $f[0];
}
```

NOTE: Is `/^[^,]+/` better suited?

Comment: `explode(',',$str)[0]` will do the trick

Comment: Before invoking anything regex based, look for a simple solution first

Comment: Why doesn't anyone using `preg_match`?

Comment: @Becky, it's overkill. Regular expressions require more processing, so unless you like that, go for the efficient, short solutions.

Comment: `[,]+` matches one or more commas… it's rather useless if you're trying to match the value *before* the comma…

Comment: What do you want to get in `$firstVal` if there are no commas?

Comment: @trincot If no comma(s), I want to use it as it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`strtok`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtok.php):

```
$firstVal = strtok($str, ",")
```

Comment: Greatly overlooked and obscure function perfect for this use case!

Comment: Thanks +10. What if I need to anyway check if the string has commas before `$firstVal = strtok($str, ",")` ?

Comment: You can check with something like: `if (strpos($str, ",") !== false)`.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to achieve this.

1. Using [substr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php)

   ```
   echo substr($str,0,strrpos($str,','));
   ```
2. Using [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

   ```
   $result = explode(',',$str);
   echo $result[0];
   ```
3. Using [strstr()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strstr.php)

   ```
   echo strstr($str, ',', true);
   ```

Comment: That depends on what you're expecting. Let's say if the input is just "abcd" with no commas. Should it output abcd? Or blank since there are no commas?

Comment: if comma(s) -> get first value. If no comma use the full string.

Comment: In that case the explode code will work just fine. You don't need any additional if.

Answer (score -1):

Explode, validate and print.

```
$values = explode(',',$str);
if(key_exists(0,$values) &&  trim($values[0])!=""){
  echo $values[0];
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain `key_exists(0,$values) &&  $values[0]!=""`?\

Comment: "," <--that's there to handle corner cases for strings like i mentioned

Comment: `explode` *always* returns an array with at least one element in it, even for empty strings. The only thing you might be interested in is to check if `values[0]` is empty or not, which means `$str` was empty to begin with.

Comment: @deceze fine but how about space?

Comment: Well, then it's a space. `var_dump(explode(",", " "))` → `array(1) { [0] => string(1) " " }`

Comment: @deceze ofcourse but does that user need to print empty value too? I just added that case ti avoid empty value..op can modify as I just wanted to give him a clue.

Comment: Your code doesn't catch the space case either… But any way, at the very least you can remove `key_exists` (which isn't a function anyway), because it'll always be `true`.

Comment: @deceze good point .. key_exists is an Alias of array_key_exists()  http://php.net/manual/en/function.key-exists.php and yes there needs to be a trim to cater that case..updating the answer

Comment: Oops, `key_exists` *does* exist. Never stumbled across it. I stand corrected on that point.